# Moving from Laravel to Node | AWS S3 put object into bucket returns suddenly 403 access denied | Credentials did no change

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am moving from my laravel backend to nodejs and at one point I am uploading a file into an AWS S3 bucket.

In laravel I was using `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`. I simply added the credentials in .env and was putting the file into the bucket with a single line of code:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ACCESS
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SECRET
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
AWS_BUCKET=BUCKETNAME

Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, $data['base64img']);
```

In nodejs I always get a 403 access denied error, eventhough the credentials work for laravel. I have already checked the credentials 100 times, they are 100% correct and the same as in the laravel project.

Here is the node code:

```
export const sendPhotoToBucket = async (filename: string, photo: string) => {
  const config = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_IMAGES,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_IMAGES,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  };

  const s3 = new S3Client(config);
  const params = {
    Body: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${photo}`,
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_IMAGES,
    Key: filename,
  };

  await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
  
  s3.destroy();
};
```